# nodejs stops responding after 1 call to S3/SQS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I am performing a simple process in nodejs/expressjs using the aws-sdk module:

1. upload file (using browser form post)
2. send it to AWS S3
3. put a message in AWS SQS for further processing.
4. respond to the client with the SQS return object.

The code below works perfectly, but only one time.  After the first post of a file, the node app no longer responds to other posts or actions (it even stops any process I have running with SetInterval(method,10000).  When I try to post a second file, it just hangs.  If I restart the server it works fine for just one post.  I am running nodejs-v0.10.9 inside WebStorm 5 IDE.  The code that the client is routed to after the file is posted is below - queueXml:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var step = require('step');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./lib/aws/config.json');

var bucketName = 'xxxxxx';
var sqsEndPoint = 'http://xxxx';

exports.queueXml = function(req,res){
  var key = getGuid();
  step(
    function readPostedFile(){
        fs.readFile(req.files.postedfile.path, this);
    },
    function sendToS3(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;

        var s3Bucket = new AWS.S3({params:{Bucket: bucketName}});
        var fileData = {Bucket: bucketName, Key: key, Body: data};
        s3Bucket.putObject(fileData,this);
    },
    function sendSQSMessage(err, path){
        if(err) throw err;

        var sqs = new AWS.SQS();
        var message = {Bucket:bucketName, Key:key};
        sqs.sendMessage({QueueUrl:sqsEndPoint,MessageBody:JSON.stringify(message)},this);
    },
    function end(err, data){
        if(err) throw err;

        res.send(JSON.stringify(data));
    }

  )

}
```

Comment: Why are you passing "this" as the callback to fs.readFile().  What "this" is is hard to determine sometimes.  What is it in this case?

Comment: Sorry - I am using Step so "this" is calling the next function as a callback passing err and data. In this case "this" is calling function sendToS3.  Likewise, "this" in sendToS3 is calling sendSQSMessage.  sendSQSMessage is calling end.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code using Node-inspector and seeing what happens the second time?

Comment: To add more clarity to the problem. The first POST is blocking the thread, even after res.send() is called.  The client receives the message from res.send within a second.  But many seconds later, node logs "Request aborted" and the next request is allowed to proceed.  This problem only occurs when I call res.send() in either the S3 or the SQS callback.  Works absolutely fine if I call res.send() in the fs.readFile callback.

Comment: I have a work around, but not sure why this works.

Comment: In the "end" function if I wrap the res.send(JSON.stringify(data) in a setTimeout, everything works as expected on first call and every subsequent call.  Therefore I just changed the line to setTimeout(function(){res.send(JSON.stringify(data));},10);.  I'll keep debugging until I find the root cause.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I also use s3 (s3 only) and node also sometime hans till I restart it. Don't know the reason for it.